# SoapUI property transfer

Tags: soapui

The response to my SOAP request is:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:deliveries nextSequence="492hi" xmlns:ns2="http://blahblahblah"/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How do I get the nextSequence value using soapui property transfer? I tried with this but I got the whole response:

```
declare namespace ns2='http://blahblahblah';
//ns2:deliveries
```

Comment: could you supply the rest of the soap request?  If that is the entire request, what you have written should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try,

```
     declare namespace ns2='http://blahblahblah';
     //ns2:deliveries[1]/@nextSequence
```

Comment: I got null, I want the nextSequence value of: 492hi to be stored in a variable

Comment: Thanks. I was using XQuery option and the above works when I unchecked it

Comment: @Suha, are you able to take a look at this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390574/soapui-restful-service-questions . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use firstObject tool for generating Xpath or you can use //ns2:deliveries[@nextSequence]..it will print all the nextSequences inside deliveries node.Go through:http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: I am getting the whole text nextSeq [<ns2:deliveries nextSequence="4936w" xmlns:ns2="http://blahhhhhh"/>] I only want the nextSequence value i.e. 4936w